# Printing a table over multiple pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am doing a project for my employer, and trying to print a large data table over multiple pages for printing purposes.

When I am trying to print the table however, the top borders seem to overlap onto the previous page.

Image preview:

[image: My Border Issue]

I have tried editing the borders to be different thicknesses, and applying the CSS properties to now allow a  to be split over multiple pages, however none of it has had any effect.

Right now I have removed all CSS from the page apart from Bootstrap and the page break rules, but am still having the same issue

My code:

```css
table {
  page-break-inside: auto
}

tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto
}

thead {
  display: table-header-group
}

tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group
}
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered thead-light">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date / Time</th>
      <th scope="col">Log Class</th>
      <th scope="col">Reason</th>
      <th scope="col">Detail</th>
      <th scope="col">Hold State</th>
      <th scope="col">UL ID</th>
      <th scope="col">SKU</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Destination</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">User</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    Table Data
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would have expected the borders to remain on the page which the  starts, and not clip onto the previous page, however as you can see in the original image, it is still clipping.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your real issue but i think you are trying to give different border to `th`, `td` then add different class to required one and add border css.

Example:

```css
.border-style {
  border:2px solid red !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td >Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td class="border-style">Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. Sorry if I phrased it badly. If you look at my screenshot, the border from the tr on the bottom page, shows at the bottom of the top page.

Answer (score 0):

I got your  issue  but not sure why   try to inspect  that and do a css display:none;  if anything  on that border

Cant find the issue  because i cant inspect on that

Sorry

And check  if anywhere  you add a display:inline-block   i have a issue with this recently

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and unfortunately I didn't find a proper solution - but read on!

The issue seemed to be that the top border from the table header 'leaked' over to the previous page. After some trial an error I found two workarounds (short of deleting the project entirely).

### "Solution" #1 - Remove stylings :'(

Removing all borders **AND BACKGROUNDS** on the top row (including the table border) meant that the leaking pixels are invisible. Hurrah!

```css
@media print {
    table, thead tr, thead th {

        /* You might not need '!important' with your styling, but
           I found with bootstrap that this is the safest option. */

        background: none !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Awww...</th>
            <th>These</th>
            <th>are</th>
            <th>boring</th>
            <th>headers!</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

But while this fixed my issue, it broke my heart. This wasn't the solution I needed...

### "Solution" #2 - Hack at it 'till it breaks!

After some considerable crying, I found that I could add another dummy row above my headers and remove the styling on that instead!

*"What a terrible solution - thanks Mark!"*

```css
th {
    border: solid 1px hotpink;
}

@media not print {
    .print-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <!-- This is where the magic is. This row 'pads' the table 
             headers and keeps them on the same page -->
        <tr class="print-only">
            <th style="border: none !important; background: none !important;"></th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <th>Look</th>
            <th>at</th>
            <th>these</th>
            <th>stylish</th>
            <th>headers!</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

So yeah... when one of you coding geniuses (genii?) come across this answer and realize that the rest of us are down shit's creek, please feel free to post a real solution to this headache :)